# ¿Como evitar que el contenido de una solicitud se pierda al redireccionar URLs usando la directiva RewriteRule?

Tags: php, .htaccess, post, apache2, mod-rewrite

Después de mucho indagar, al fin me ha quedado claro que, por motivos de seguridad (supongo) el contenido de una solicitud, en mi caso **POST**, se pierde al hacer una **redirección de URL** como esta:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /proyectoMascotas
RewriteRule ^mascotas api/mascotas.php
```

Exacto, estoy intentando hacer una **APIrest** y para hacerlo correctamente necesito hacer una solicitud **POST** enviando los datos de la mascota en **JSON**.

La variable

```
$_POST[]
```

está **vacía** así como el contenido de

```
file_get_contents('php://input');
```

La única forma de acceder al objeto JSON es usando la variable:

```
$GLOBALS["_SERVER"]["HTTP_{NOMBRE DEL OBJETO}"];
```

Lo cual es un poco sucio. Más allá de que pueda ser poco fiable.

**¿Existe algún modo de redirigir el contenido de la solicitud al punto final?**

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Ejemplo de consulta:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1/proyectomascotas/mascotas/' \
--header 'BODY: {"nombre":"pepe","edad":10}' \
--data-raw ''
```

PD. Estoy usando PHP y APACHE, con las reglas de redirección escritas en un .htaccess.  Estoy usando [Postman para realizar las peticiones.](https://www.postman.com/)

Comment: ¿Cómo estás enviando la petición? Los datos están llegando en encabezados y puedes acceder a ellos desde [$_SERVER](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: Estoy enviando un texto en formato JSON. Lo he intentado incluir tanto en el header como el body del mensaje. Estoy usando el método POST. Exacto, tal y como digo, la variable $_SERVER o $GLOBALS["_SERVER"], contienen el mensaje pero no en formato JSON, sino en este formato  "clave,valor,clave,valor," separado por comas y difícil de tratar.

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el código que usas para enviar la petición, es ahí donde realmente está el problema.

Comment: Perdonen olviden mi comentario, el formato JSON es bien recibido, sin embargo sigo manteniendo el interés en encontrar una forma más limpia de acceder al contenido del de header de una solicitud redireccionada.

Comment: Última pregunta: ¿Por qué usas un comando del sistema operativo en lugar de la librería [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.curl.php) de PHP? Hay [ejemplos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/curl.examples-basic.php) para enviar datos por POST sin complicaciones.

Comment: Bueno, realmente estoy usando  Postman, un cliente para hacer peticiones y visualizar respuestas. Existiendo este tipo de software no veo la necesidad de programar un cliente para testar mi APIrest. En Postman puedo visualizar el comando curl que utiliza a la hora de hacer una petición y es el que he copiado y pegado aquí.